# What do these typedefs mean in C ? What are they declaring?

Tags: c, types, definition

```
typedef double (*func_t) (double);
```

and

```
typedef struct symrec symrec;
```

symrec is btw a structure previously defined. But funct_t is not mentioned anywhere, and I do not know is this is valid, and what is means.

I could look into the specifications of typedef, I know, but that would take ages, since I have no experience doing that. I would just like some input from someone that has enough experience to explain this in simple terms.

I'm not a newbie in C, but never came across this.

Comment: google `typedef in C`...

Comment: Can anyone save me time and reputation by just putting into simple short text then precise meaning of these two lines, if thats not too much to ask of?

Comment: I think there is a pretty good (and concise) explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef).

Comment: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html or look at the cdecl program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### typedef double (*func_t) (double);

This names a type `func_t` which is for a function pointer that takes one argument of type `double` and returns a value of type `double`.

#### typedef struct symrec symrec;

This creates an alias for `struct symrec` called `symrec`. So you can then do either `struct symrec foo;` or `symrec foo;`, both of which have the same result.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I know what to further research with typedef of function pointers. Still a couple of details im interested in the definition.